# How to web scrape all of the batters names?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I would like to scrape all of the MLB batters stats for 2018. Here is my code so far:

```
#import modules

from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import html

#fetch url/html

response = urlopen("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard-batting.shtml")
content = response.read()
tree = html.fromstring( content )

#parse data

comment_html = tree.xpath('//comment()[contains(., "players_standard_batting")]')[0]
comment_html = str(comment_html).replace("-->", "")
comment_html = comment_html.replace("<!--", "")
tree = html.fromstring( comment_html )
for batter_row in tree.xpath('//table[@id="players_standard_batting"]/tbody/tr[contains(@class, "full_table")]'):
    csk = batter_row.xpath('./td[@data-stat="player"]/@csk')[0]
```

When I scraped all of the batters there is 0.01 attached to each name. I tried to remove attached numbers using the following code:

```
bat_data = [csk]
string = '0.01'
result = []

for x in bat_data :
    if string in x:
        substring = x.replace(string,'')
        if substring != "":
            result.append(substring)
    else:
        result.append(x)
print(result)
```

This code removed the number, however, only the last name was printed:

Output:

```
['Zunino, Mike']
```

Also, there is a bracket and quotations around the name. The name is also in reverse order.

1) How can I print all of the batters names?

2) How can I remove the quotation marks and brackets?

3) Can I reverse the order of the names so the first name gets printed and then the last name?

The final output I am hoping for would be all of the batters names like so: Mike Zunino.

I am new to this site... I am also new to scraping/coding and will greatly appreciate any help I can get! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same in different ways. Here is one such approach which doesn't require post processing. You get the names how you wanted to get:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard-batting.shtml"

content = str(urlopen(url).read())
comment = content.replace("-->","").replace("<!--","")
tree = fromstring(comment)
for batter_row in tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"stats_table")]//tr[contains(@class,"full_table")]'):
    csk = batter_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]/a')[0].text
    print(csk)
```

Output you may get like:

```
Jose Abreu
Ronald Acuna
Jason Adam
Willy Adames
Austin L. Adams
```

Comment: this is precisely what I was looking for. You deserve more than just a check mark... Thank you sir! =)

Comment: Thanks again @SIM! If I could please trouble you for one more question, sir... If I have 2 different categories to scrape - csk1 and csk2, for example - how can I save both to a dataframe using pandas so I can export to excel?

Comment: Sorry @Able Archer, I have almost zero knowledge on dataframe so I can't help you there.

Comment: No worries at all @SIM... you have helped tremendously to my learning! For that I thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

**1) Print all batter names**

```
print(result)
```

This will print everything in the result object. If it’s not printing what you expect then there’s something else wrong going on.

**2) Remove quotations**
The brackets are due to it being an array object. Try this...

```
print(result[0])
```

This will tell the interpreter to print result at the 0 index.

**3) Reverse order of names**

Try

```
name = result[0].split(“ “).reverse()[::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply =) I receive this error @Kenpachi:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xboss\Desktop\Pitchers in progress.py", line 37, in <module>
    name = result[0].split(" ").reverse().join()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: I just edited my reversal solution and I tested it this time in python this will print out the name in the proper order!

Comment: Ty @Kenpachi!! I really appreciate your time!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You get only the last batter because you are overwriting the value of csk each time in your first loop. Initialize the empty list bat_data first and then add each batter to it.

```
bat_data= []
for batter_row in blah:
    csk = blah
    bat_data.append(csk)
```

This will give you a list of all batters, `['Abreu,Jose0.01', 'Acuna,Ronald0.01', 'Adam,Jason0.01', ...]`

Then loop through this list but you don't have to check if `string` is in the name. Just do `x.replace('0.01', '')` and then check if the string is empty.

To reverse the order of the names

```
substring = substring.split(',')
substring.reverse()
nn = " ".join(substring)
```

Then append nn to the result.

You are getting the quotes and the brackets because you are printing the list. Instead iterate through the list and print each item.

Your code edited assuming you got bat_data correctly:

```
for x in bat_data :
    substring = x.replace(string,'')
    if substring != "":
        substring = substring.split(',')
        substring.reverse()
        substring = ' '.join(substring)
        result.append(substring)

for x in result:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @RajeshM! Is there any way you can show me the complete code or update my code? I am not sure where to make the adjustments. I tried to run the code a couple different way but ran into some issues. I am sure it's something I am doing wrong.

Comment: My earlier code had a problem. Check updated code above.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this and try to learn from it. I will get back to you in the near future. Thanks for taking the time out of your busy day. Truly grateful, sir. =)